# Mysql - Count how many rows have a certain number?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, aggregate-functions

I have a query that checks a tables and groups all entries from a user and counts those entries

```
  SELECT username, 
         count(userid)  
    FROM orders 
GROUP BY userid
```

This returns a list of username's and how many orders they have submitted

```
username  count(userid)
------------------------
test      1  
test2     1  
test3     3  
test4     3  
test4     3  
test4     3
```

What i want the query to do is count how many users have X orders and return that number.

So from the above results users that have 1 order should be 2 and users that have 3 orders should be 4. So on and so forth can this be done?

Comment: Note: When testing (in SQL server, since that's what I have at hand), you have to change your GROUP BY to "userid, username" to get it to work (first, can't include username in the SELECT list if it's not in the GROUP BY, and second, if you just change the GROUP BY to "username", then the last 3 rows of your data will all be combined together).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT o.username, 
               COUNT(o.userid) AS cnt
          FROM ORDERS o
      GROUP BY o.userid
        HAVING cnt = ?) x
```

Replace "?" with the number you want to see the number of users with that count value.

Comment: same thing i get Error Code: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @William Smith: Fixed, forgot to add the table alias (the "x").

Answer (score 3):

I'd think you could just add something like this around your query:

```
SELECT InnerCount, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    -- your query
    SELECT username, count(userid) AS InnerCount
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY userid
) t1
GROUP BY InnerCount
```

(Caveat: haven't touched mysql in years)

Comment: i get this error

Error Code: 1248
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: I edited it to add the "t1" alias after the right parenthesis after it failed for me too.